# Diagnosing collinearity in a Cox proportional hazards model

Tags: r, prediction, multicollinearity

I am building a Cox Proportional Hazards Model to predict the survival outcome of seabird faced with predation pressure. I have 6 factor variables with two or three levels each that I have predicted to affect survival. Three of which are management relevant (they can be manipulated by wildlife managers to increase or decrease survival if significant). The ultimate goal of the model is prediction but I would like to include the management relevant variables as well even if not significant. How can I check for multicollinearity among my variables. I am using program R for the analysis.

Comment: Consider how important it is to check for multicollinearity in your application, especially if prediction is your main goal. All variables related to outcome contain information for prediction, even if they do not turn out "significant" in a particular sample. Problems from multicollinearity often arise from attempts to eliminate individual predictor variables, leading to sometimes counter-intuitive effects on the relations of the remaining variables to outcome. For the management-related variables, you will have to do experiments in any event to validate your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Almost) perfect multicollinearity (MC) will lead to large standard errors of the estimates and/or non-convergence of the optimization routines. Any other MC is no issue since your goal is prediction (and not interpretation of effects).